# reloading visible uicollectionviewcell when nested in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollection that shows a padlock on cells that locked to users who aren't logged in. The user can view the collection and then login in a modal. When the modal dismisses, I am trying to reload the cells of the table and the nested collection to remove the padlocks from the cells.

The visible cells are not refreshing to remove the padlock.  When the collection is scrolled, the cells offscreen are correct and show with padlock. I am calling reloaddata() on both the tableview and each nested collectionview.

The code I have is separated to:

### UIViewController

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionWorkouts", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

        // Return the workouts count from the section
        let intIndex = indexPath.row

        let index = workoutSections.startIndex.advancedBy(intIndex)

        let currentWorkoutSectionKey = workoutSections.keys[index]

        if let currentWorkoutSection = workoutSections[currentWorkoutSectionKey] {

            cell.workoutsCollection.dataSource = sectionWorkoutsCell
            cell.workoutsCollection.delegate = sectionWorkoutsCell

            cell.updateCellWithWorkouts(currentWorkoutSectionKey, workouts: currentWorkoutSection)


        }

    }

    return cell
}
```

### UITableViewCell

```
class SectionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var workouts = [Workout]()
    var delegate: WorkoutCellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var sectionTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var workoutsCollection: UICollectionView!

    func updateCellWithWorkouts(title: String, workouts: [Workout]){

        self.sectionTitle.text = title
        self.workouts = workouts
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.workoutsCollection.reloadData()
        })

    }


    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("SectionWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionCollectionViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row

        let workout = workouts[row]

        cell.configCell(workout)

        return cell

    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workouts.count
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let row = indexPath.row
        let feature = workouts[row]

        if let delegate = self.delegate{
            delegate.didSelectWorkoutCell(feature)
        }

    }

}
```

### UICollectionViewCell

```
class SectionCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

 @IBOutlet weak var imageContainer: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var tintOverlay: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var padlock: UIImageView!

 @IBOutlet weak var workoutTitle: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var duration: UILabel!

 var locked = true

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

  }


  func configCell(workout: Workout){

    self.workoutTitle.text = workout.name

    if workout.type == "Free" || AccountManager.userIsLoggedInMember() {
        self.setToUnLocked()
    }else{
        self.setToLocked()
    }

    self.layoutIfNeeded()

  }


  func setToUnLocked(){
    locked = false
    tintOverlay.alpha = 0
    padlock.alpha = 0
  }


  func setToLocked(){
    locked = true
    tintOverlay.alpha = 0.6
    padlock.alpha = 1
  }

}
```

Comment: You should set a breakpoint at `AccountManager.userIsLoggedInMember() ` and check its value. You might be refreshing the tableview before updating this value

Comment: try to debug using breakpoint in the setToUnLocked function if its called for visible cells or not.

Comment: Like the comments above, It looks like the mistake is somewhere else. Where are you calling the tableView.reloadData()? And were does your break point get to? What exact function is not called ? Plus, there is no reason for you to use "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main" since you are already are on main at "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

Comment: I have set some breakpoints.  When the table and collection views reload the cell debug is showing that the cells data is updated and should be showing the correct data.  I also checked the alpha attribute of the tintOverlay after reloads and it says that is changing but it isn't visually updating

Comment: try calling self.setNeedsLayout() instead of self.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 4):

You should probably move the call to configure the cell to the `willDisplayCell:` method instead. You can remove it from the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. This is the correct time to configure any visual aspects of the cell to be displayed.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell,
    forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row

    let workout = workouts[row]

    cell.configCell(workout)

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I didn't know there was a willDisplayCell method.  I have tried it and unfortunately it hasn't solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that:
the tableViewCell owns the data that is used for configuring the collectionViewCell.

---

If you want your collectionViewCell to update without the need for tableView.reloadData, the data that is used for configuring the collectionViewCell(in your case 'workout') must be fetched from elsewhere than from the tableViewCell.